# Property 'Header' does not exist on type 'typeof Accordion'. TS2339

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have this class-based Accordion component having type AccordionComposition. But It throws me this error

> Property 'Header' does not exist on type 'typeof Accordion'.  TS2339

> Property 'Content' does not exist on type 'typeof Accordion'.  TS2339

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, Component } from "react";
    import {
      FAQAnswer,
      FAQQuestion,
      Icon,
      SpanIcon,
      CloseIcon,
      FAQBadge,
    } from "./styles";
    import useAccordion from "../../hooks/useAccordion";
    import { AccordionProvider } from "../../context/AccordionContext";
    import {
      AccordionComposition,
      QuestionProps,
    } from "../../interfaces/Accordion";
    
    type State = {
      activeItem: boolean;
    };
    
    class Accordion extends Component<AccordionComposition> {
      constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.setActiveItem = this.setActiveItem.bind(this);
      }
      state: State = {
        activeItem: false,
      };
      setActiveItem(active: boolean) {
        this.setState({ activeItem: active });
      }
      // const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState<boolean>(false);
    
      render() {
        const { activeItem } = this.state;
        let setActiveItem = this.setActiveItem;
    
        return (
          <AccordionProvider value={{ activeItem, setActiveItem }}>
            {this.props.children}
          </AccordionProvider>
        );
      }
    }
    Accordion.Header = Header;
    Accordion.Content = Content;
```

My Header component:

```
const Header: React.FunctionComponent<QuestionProps> = ({
  children,
  category,
}) => {
  const { setActiveItem, activeItem } = useAccordion();

  return (
    <FAQQuestion onClick={() => setActiveItem(!activeItem)}>
      {children}
      <div>
        <FAQBadge>{category}</FAQBadge>
        <Icon>
          {activeItem ? (
            <CloseIcon onClick={() => setActiveItem(false)} />
          ) : (
            <SpanIcon onClick={() => setActiveItem(true)} />
          )}
        </Icon>
      </div>
    </FAQQuestion>
  );
};
```

My Content Component:

```
const Content: FunctionComponent = ({ children }) => {
  const { activeItem } = useAccordion();

  return <FAQAnswer isOpen={activeItem}>{children}</FAQAnswer>;
};
```

My Type Definition of Accordion Composition

```
export interface AccordionComposition {
  Content: React.FunctionComponent;
  Header: React.FunctionComponent<QuestionProps>;
}
```

Comment: Could also mention where it throws that error?

Comment: I throws an error on this line
```Accordion.Header = Header;
    Accordion.Content = Content;```